# pivottable js how to add colspan and row span

Tags: angular, pivottable.js

im using *pivottable.js* in *Angular 4*
How to get col span in table like
[see here colspan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_th_colspan)
and how to add table title

My table should look like this
[See Table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zymex.png)

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about what your data looks like and what you want to see?

Comment: hi I have added table image , right now i dnt have data i'm designing tables , based on structure how my data should be, can we have sub-types in row values?

Comment: how to avoid null in cols, suppose one object of input does not have col attribute it display null, how to handle not to display null or not to display cell there.